# store large text in sql and show in asp .net page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to store text description about 50000 character or more than it in Sql Server. I'm using FCK Editor and 3 tier architecture in my application. And then I want to retrieve that data and show all the text in the application. If the description is huge then it can be shown Page wise.

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm sending data through Business Layer where code like: There is a size which I have given 10000 and I need that should be of any length.(The Text should be go through Business Layer)                                                                                           localOutPutServer.BuildParameter("@lessonDesc", lessonDesc, DataServer.SQLDataType.SQLString,10000, ParameterDirection.Input);

Comment: Well, then i suggest you update your Business layer to not be totally limiting.

Answer (score 1):

`varchar(max)` can store 2,147,483,647 characters well within your limits

Comment: Please see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

you can choose data type nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text Datatype,

TEXT is used for large pieces of string data.

TEXT is good:

```
If you need to store large texts in your database
If you do not search on the value of the column
If you select this column rarely and do not join on it.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql server 2005 or 2008 as database then please try the **text data type**. because text data type is used for to store unlimited string data. **As Per my knowledge**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing entire data as single record,You can store it in multiple rows.Keep columns to identify the file and order of row in your table.

```
    Create table Textfiledata
    (
    File_ID Numeric(10,0),
    File_Data Varchar(8000),
    Order Numeric(10,0),
    )

insert into Textfiledata(1,"some text",0);
insert into Textfiledata(1,"some text",1);
```